# Copy pasteing concatenated date time values from Excel in the same format as it's seen in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have date time cells in Excel. I have a column that concatenates those date time cells.

When I copy paste a value from a date time cell to, say, notepad++, the value shows correctly, like: 6.1.2016 23:00

But when I copy paste the contents of the column that concatenates all the date time values, the values show in following format: 42375,875

I need to copy paste from excel to an sql script, and of course sql thinks that the comma separates two different values, which isn't the case.

How I can copy paste all of them in this format: 6.1.2016 23:00 and **NOT** in this format: 42375,875

Answer (score 2):

try like this

note : i have have used here **m.dd.yyyy** date format. you can change it as per your requirement

`=TEXT(DATE,"m.dd.yyyy ")&TEXT(TIME,"hh:mm")`

if dates are in Column **A** and time in Column **B**
paste this formula in column **C**

`=TEXT(A2,"m.dd.yyyy ")&TEXT(B2,"hh:mm")`

Comment: To add to above and maybe a word of caution.
Depending on what version of TSQL you are using you may not have the option to use the DataTime data type. In my experience if you haven't this facility then you need to put the date and time in the the following format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS. The number you see on the excel sheet is the same date time but represented differently. You can (as others have suggested) click on the cell and change the format in to a more conventional format to make it look right.

Answer (score 2):

42375.875 is the internal representation of the DateTime value (1/6/2016  9:00:00 PM) and it seems correct. Just set the Excel Cell format to Date (from Menu) and it should display the correct Date value. T-SQL will `DateTime` field should also recognize the number 42375.875 representing the correct date. Hope this may help.